# flask wtform - access object in different function

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

Is it possible in flask to seperate GET and POST to 2 functions and access the created wtform in the POST function?

```
@app.route('/foo', methods=['GET'])
def foo_get():
    ... 
    form = MyForm() # Initialize form
    ...
    return render_template('foo.html', form=form)

@app.route('/foo', methods=['POST'])
def foo_post():
    ...
    # POST function for foo's form
    # access form here?
```

Answer (score 3):

Create another form instance. That's exactly what would happen when submitting the form to the same function too, there's no "memory" of local variables between requests.